# Problems Installing lxml with python/django

Tags: python, django, lxml

I am trying to use lxml in one of my projects in django, but I am having trouble installing the lxml module.  I am using Ubuntu 10.04.  I have looked on the web for suitable tutorials on how to install the lxml module, but I never seem to understand it correctly.  Would anyone be able to clearly tell me how to install this module?

Thank you,

Steve

Comment: What have you done, and how hasn't it worked?

Comment: I have tried using the easy_install to install the module but it keeps telling me it can't find the correct headers?

Comment: Try installing and building libxml2 first before lxml.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apt-get install python-lxml
```